# Focus a new client in the `awful.layout.suit.max` layout

Tags: awesome-wm

I am coming from i3 and I only used two layouts tiled and stacked. I am currently looking for a way to get the stacked layout into awesome.

It seems that `awful.layout.suit.max` is very close to what I want. The problem that I have is that I can't seem to focus any clients.

`awful.client.focus.bydirection` doesn't seem to do anything with the `max` layout. I looked at how `awful.layout.suit.max` and `awful.layout.suit.max` and there doesn't seem to be anything special.

So I assume `awful.client.focus.bydirection` doesn't work because the clients are stacked. `awful.client.focus.byidx(-1)` doesn't seem to do anything.

How would I select a new client in the `awful.layout.suit.max` layout?

Comment: Could you open some terminals and type in them? That should make it obvious if `awful.client.focus.byidx(-1)` did what it is supposed to do, since you are typing in another terminal now. Besides that: I am using basically the default config and the max layout works for me as expected with Mod4+j/k (which is `focus.byidx`).

Comment: Hm you are right. `focus.byidx` does not work at all for me. I might have changed something that made it break.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't wrap the `focus.byidx` function call in another function, and so it just didn't get called at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try my [Collision](https://github.com/elv13/collision) module. It has all the necessary logic to support geometric navigation. This includes rather hacky tricks to work with all default layouts.